# Freeing memory allocated for string in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, trie

I'm stuck at a problem with memory allocation and freeing it.

I'm trying to implement a dictionary using a compressed trie (Patricia). I have a trie library which works correctly when I call its functions from main. However, I have a little problem when I'm trying to parse input.

I have a parser library which reads a word from the standard input and calls the `insert` function from the trie library. It calls it this way:

```
void tryInsert(char *commandLine, struct tree *t) {
        char *arg[3] = { NULL };
        sscanf(commandLine, "%ms %ms%ms", &arg[0], &arg[1], &arg[2]);
        if (arg[1] == 0 || arg[2] != 0 || !consistsOfSmallCases(arg[1]))
                printf("ignored\n");
        else
                //inserting arg[1] into tree
                insert(t, arg[1]);
//      free(arg[0]);
//      free(arg[1]);
//      free(arg[2]);
}
```

The three calls of the "free" function are now marked as commets, because:

the `insert` function has two argument: a trie and a `char *word`. Inside this function, I insert a **suffix** of `word` into some a new of the trie. This means that I don't want to free the memory that's allocated for the string right away.

However, since I'm only inserting a **suffix**, I lose control of the prefix.

Which means that if, inside a `clear` function that clears the trie, I call `free(node->content)`, I don't actually free all the memory allocated.

Moreover, when try and copy the string `word` into `char word1[256]` inside the `insert` function and un-comment those thee frees, everything stops working.

I would appreciate any ideas how to deal with that,

Comment: Where are you allocating memory? you only allocated an array of pointers

Comment: Whoa. I've never seen `%ms`, had to [check the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Comment: @Leeor
during sscanf

Comment: as someone already said, you are initialising the array of pointers to zero, but not actually allocating any memory for those pointers

Comment: I think we need the `insert` function to answer your question. Your last sentence is somewhat cryptic without it.

Comment: @cerkiewny The `%ms` flag allocates memory using malloc and expects a `char**` as its argument.

Comment: oh i see thats smart then :)

Answer (score 2):

You have some logic errors in your code, which is always scary when dealing with dynamic memory.

The `insert()` function needs to do a copy of the part of the string that it wishes to store, since it only wants a prefix.

Also, you *really* should check that `sscanf()` succeeds before relying on the variables having valid values. If it doesn't return `3`, there was a parsing problem and not all of the strings will have been allocated. Check the return value.

Comment: What do you mean sscanf() succeeds?

Comment: `sscanf` returns the number of variables stored, so if it didn't return 3 something happened. It could also return `EOF`, in which case you should check `ferror` for the reason. It's all in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

Comment: Thanks. C is indeed a disgusting language ;)